# How to update treeview when used edits listview/Gridview bound to same data?

Tags: c#, xaml, listview

I have a set of collections based on a class called "Foo", and the class includes a property "Bar", along with a fairly long list of other values to be displayed and edited.

I am using two semi-independent UI elements that use the "Foo" collection in an "explorer" like display with a TreeView on one side and a detail ListView on the other.  The Treeview has collection of Foo collections (like a folder or registry key with subitems) that has subitems that are the individual Foos.  Which collection item it belongs under is dictated by the Bar property. You can think of this like a Foo that is a file and a property of the file is the file path.

Each Foo is displayed in a custom UserControl. If you click on a "container of Foos" on the left TreeView, the SelectionChanged method displays the Foos that are in that collection in the right ListView, and if you click on a specific Foo item on the left it displays just that Foo in the right ListView.

This is all working well and we can change the Bar setting in the ListView and have it update the underlying data and display within ListView (using INotifyPropertyChanged).

What I'd like is to have the changed Bar value, changed in the ListView, affect the ListView display on the left automatically.

Any ideas on how to accomplish this (or reorganize to get the same effect)?